# The service name is invalid while starting EM on oracle 11g on windows

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I am trying to start EM on oracle 11g on Windows. When I performed

```
emctl start dbconsole
```

It shows

```
The service name is invalid more help is available on net helpmsg 2185
```

and when I wrote

```
net helpmsg 2185
```

it shows same thing "the service name is invalid"

What will be the right solution for this?